# How to limit Airflow to run only one instance of a DAG run at a time?

Tags: airflow

I want the tasks in the DAG to all finish before the 1st task of the next run gets executed.

I have max_active_runs = 1, but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxe54.png) still happens.

```
default_args = {
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'wait_for_downstream': True,
    'max_active_runs': 1,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 03, 04),
    'owner': 't.n',
    'email': ['t.n@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 3,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=4)
}

dag = DAG('example', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval = schedule_interval)
```

(All of my tasks are dependent on the previous task. Airflow version is 1.8.0)

Thank you

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I changed to put `max_active_runs` as an argument of `DAG()` instead of in **default_arguments**, and it worked.

Thanks SimonD for giving me the idea, though not directly pointing to it in your answer.

Comment: This working in which version? I'm using 1.10.14. It is still running all the dag runs simultaneously.

Comment: This was answered for 1.8.0

Comment: What happens to the next execution date if max_active_runs=1 and the run takes longer than the schedule interval?

Answer (score 67):

You've put the `'max_active_runs': 1` into the `default_args` parameter and not into the correct spot.

`max_active_runs` is a constructor argument for a DAG and should not be put into the `default_args` dictionary.

Here is an example DAG that shows where you need to move it to:

```py
dag_args = { 
    'owner': 'Owner',
    # 'max_active_runs': 1, # <--- Here is where you had it.
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 01, 1, 12, 00),
    'email_on_failure': False
}

sched = timedelta(hours=1)
dag = DAG(
          job_id, 
          default_args=dag_args, 
          schedule_interval=sched, 
          max_active_runs=1 # <---- Here is where it is supposed to be
      )
```

If the tasks that your dag is running are actually sub-dags then you may need to pass `max_active_runs` into the subdags too but not 100% sure on this.

Comment: I passed max_active_runs as a default argument instead. Wonder if it's the problem. Will try passing it in the DAG function and see if it works.

Comment: If you want to set this for all your DAGs, you can use set [max_active_runs_per_dag](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#max-active-runs-per-dag)

Answer (score -3):

Actually you should use DAG_CONCURRENCY=1 as environment var. Worked for me.

Comment: DAG_CONCURRENCY specifies how many tasks instances will run at the same time within a DAG and not how many instances of your DAG will run from what I understand.

Answer (score -4):

You can use xcoms to do it. First take 2 python operators as 'start' and 'end' to the DAG. Set the flow as:

> start ---> ALL TASKS ----> end

'end' will always push a variable

> last_success = context['execution_date'] to xcom (xcom_push). (Requires provide_context = True in the PythonOperators).

And 'start' will always check xcom (xcom_pull) to see whether there exists a last_success variable with value equal to the previous DagRun's execution_date or to the DAG's start_date (to let the process start).

Followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47533903/airflow-depends-on-past-for-whole-dag)

Comment: Seems like a promising workaround. Will be trying this.