# Airflow configuration recommendation for LocalExecutor

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am using airflow docker-compose [from here](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow)  and I have some performance issue along with strange behavior of airflow crashing.

First I have 5 DAGs running at the sametime, each one of them has 8 steps with `max_active_runs=1`:

```
 step1x
 step2y
 step3 >> step4 >> step8
 step3 >> step5 >> step8
 step3 >> step6 >> step8
 step3 >> step7 >> step8
```

I would like to know what configuration should I use in order to maximize Airflow parallelism vs Stability. i.e.: I want to know what is the maximum recommanded [OPTIONS BELOW] for a machine that has **X CPU** and **Y GB of RAM**. 
I am using a `LocalExecutor` but can't figure out how should I configure the parallelism:

```
AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__SCHEDULER_MAX_THREADS=?
AIRFLOW__CORE__PARALLELISM=?
AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__WORKERS=?
```

Is there a documentation that states the recommandation for each one of those based on your machine specification ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you have a parallelism problem...yet.

Can you clarify something? You have 5 different dags with similar set-ups? Or this is launching five instances of the same task at once? I'd expect the former because of the `max_active_runs` setting.

On your task declaration here:

```
 step1x
 step2y
 step3 >> step4 >> step8
 step3 >> step5 >> step8
 step3 >> step6 >> step8
 step3 >> step7 >> step8
```

Are you expecting `step1x`, `step2y` and `step3` to all execute at the same time? Then 4-7 and finally `step8`? What are you doing in the DAG where you need that kind of process vs 1-8 sequential?

Comment: yes all 5 Dags have the same set-up but uses different parameters. step1, 2 and 3 are independent and can run in parallel. The Dags are processing data from different sources with different settings. Each source is providing data every minute, so I created a Dag for each source.

Comment: [This is the best explanation I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56370720/how-can-i-control-the-parallelism-or-concurrency-of-an-airflow-dag/56370721#56370721) of how the different concurrency settings can be tuned. Might be helpful?

Comment: It is indeed helpful, thank you. But this question is different I ask for a recommendation of config in regard to the machine's capacity (in CPU & RAM) for a localExecutor