# how to limit the number of tasks run simultaneously in a specific dag on airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

I have a `Dag` in `air-flow` looks like that:

```
start >> [task1,task2,....task16] >> end
```

I want to limit the tasks that running simultaneously in this dag to be 4 for example.

I know there is `'max_active_tasks_per_dag'` parameters, but it affects on all dags and in my case I want to define it only for my dag.
how can I do so? it is even possible?

Comment: I think you are looking for `concurrency` param.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56370720/how-to-control-the-parallelism-or-concurrency-of-an-airflow-installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the description of the parameter you will find out that you can configure it per dag:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#max-active-tasks-per-dag

> max_active_tasks_per_dag New in version 2.2.0.
>
> The maximum number of task instances allowed to run concurrently in
> each DAG. To calculate the number of tasks that is running
> concurrently for a DAG, add up the number of running tasks for all DAG
> runs of the DAG. This is configurable at the DAG level with
> max_active_tasks, which is defaulted as max_active_tasks_per_dag.