# What is task parallelism in the context of airflow?

Tags: airflow

Task parallelism in general is when multiple tasks run on the same or different set of data. But what is it in the context of airflow, when I change the parallelism parameter in the airflow.cfg file?

For instance, say I want to run a data processor on a batch of data. Will setting parallelism to 32, split the data into 32 sub-batches and run the same task on those sub-batches?

Or maybe, if somehow have 32 batches of data originally, instead of 1, I am able to run the data processor on all 32 batches(ie 32 task runs at the same time).

Comment: You can check out this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200666/airflow-parallelism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting won't "split the data" within your DAG.
From the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/faq.html):

> parallelism: This variable controls the number of task instances that
> runs simultaneously across the whole Airflow cluster

If you want to parallel execution of a task you will need to break it further meaning create more tasks but each task does less work. That can be come handy for some ETLs.

**For example:**

Lets say you want to copy yesterday records from MySQL to S3.

You could do it with a single `MySQLToS3Operator` that reads yesterday data in a single query. However you can also break it to 2 `MySQLToS3Operator` reading 12 hours data or 24 operators each reading hourly data. That is up to you and the limitation of the services you are working with.