# Airflow Parallelism not Scaling

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm trying to scale my airflow jobs. We are deployed on k8s and we have a scheduler, webserver, flower, redis and 4 worker nodes. I updated the config map to have
`AIRFLOW__CORE__PARALLELISM = 40`
And from what I've read ([Airflow parallelism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200666/airflow-parallelism)) this should mean I have around 40 tasks running at a time. But looking at some DataDog Dashboards I set up, my number of task is unchanged, and still plateaus around 32.

Is there something I am missing here?

Here are a few other variables that may be related:

```
AIRFLOW__CELERY__WORKER_CONCURRENCY=8
AIRFLOW_VERSION=2.1.2
```

Also found this pretty helpful:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue is [Pools](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-pools). If all your tasks are in the default_pool and it has only 32 slots, that will cap your total number of concurrent tasks. You may also want to check out Astronomer's [Scaling Airflow](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-scaling-workers) guide.

Comment: Thanks! So I checked via the UI and my slots are 150, running is 6, and queued is 5, my expectation would be that 0 are queued since 6 < 150.