# Airflow config for running concurrent DAG tasks

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-webserver

I have multiple DAGs on my airflow env some of which has to run 32 tasks concurrently. Other DAGS are being queued while these tasks are being executed.
I have ec2 instances and 16 cpu for worker and 8cpu for scheduler.
I have set parallelism and dag_concurrency and worker_concurrency to 64. I am not sure if this an ideal way. I am able to run more than 32 tasks from different DAGs but now the DAG is in running state but the tasks are set to up_for_retry status and either run or fails after some time.
Is it better to setup multiple workers with lower cpu or should any other parameters be changed to ensure a seamless flow?

Comment: Check the following Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200666/airflow-parallelism
Also, have a look at [Airflow Pools](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/pools.html)